# Disable Model Validation [Required] in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-validation

So basically I have two classes which are Model and DTO, Model will be used to handle the APIs while the DTO will be handling the database (Firestore).

I have a **Company** model, in this model, the CompanyName is required when I'm doing CreateCompany POST request.

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the **Employee** model, which I used to create employee's details, and **Company** model will be used in this class.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public bool? IsFirstLogin { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string PaypalEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public Company company { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem is when I made a CreateEmployee POST request, I will only need the *Employee.company.CompanyId* to be filled in, but because in the Company model, the *Company.CompanyName* has set to [Required] earlier, and it made a must to fill in the *Employee.company.CompanyName* as well.

So I was thinking if there is any way I can disable the Model Validation during making a CreateEmployee POST request. Or maybe I should only enable the Model Validation during CreateCompany POST request?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom validation attribute validating `CompanyName` based on whether `Company` is inner property or top level model

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class RequiredCompanyNameAttribute: RequiredAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //validate if top level model
        if (validationContext.ObjectType == typeof(Company))
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);

        //no validation inside Employee
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        Company company = (Company)value;
        //validate CompanyName with RequiredAttribute
        return base.IsValid(company.CompanyName);
    }
}
```

And usage

```
[RequiredCompanyName]
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

But the easiest would be intoducing different models for this purpose

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeCompany
{
    [Required]
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    //..

    public EmployeeCompany Company { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the offending property from the ModelState

```
ModelState.Remove( “Company.CompanyName” );
```